# Linux Header Removal from a ppm file

Tags: linux, command

Does anybody know the command to remove the header from a ppm file in Linux? I've tried this already

```
         ´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´
         head -n 4 Example.ppm > header.txt
         tail -n 5+ Example.ppm > body.bin 
         ´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´
```

It tells me that "Tail" could not be found.

Answer (score 1):

Most ppm files use newlines in the header so your first command is fine.  However, the rest of the file is binary, so:

```
head -n 4 Example.ppm > header.txt
filesize=$(wc -c header.txt)
dd if=Example.ppm of=body.bin bs=1 skip=$filesize
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have /bin/tail if you have /bin/head; both are in the coreutils RPM package.

The format of a ppm(5) file (http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html) is awkward to use with the line-based head/tail/sed family.  The documentation describes fields separated by whitespace that is not necessarily a line break.

You will need to: 1) Ignore comments from '#' to end of line; and 2) process the remainder one field (not column, not line) at a time.  Using awk(1) could be an option here.

Check the documentation (http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/directory.html) for a list of conversion programs.  You may find one that converts the PPM file into a form better suited to whatever usage is your ultimate goal.